# Animated movie about talking cars that is not in the “Cars” franchise?

Tags: story-identification, movie

The only scene from the movie that I remember is two of the cars talking in a highway. They were going pretty slowly and talking about a race. I watched it when I was a kid and it was a DVD I think and I watched it mid 2000s, like 2007-2008.

I usually skipped this scene when I was kid because it was pretty boring, like 10 minutes long.

I definitely know that it wasn't any of the *Cars* movie, it was like a ripoff.

Comment: Do you remember the colors of the cars or their approximate make?

Comment: One was a truck I think. Maybe a pickup.

Comment: If Pixar's Cars weren't explicitly excluded here, I would seriously be proposing it. It does have a scene with the cars (and falling-asleep truck) talking while moving too slowly on a highway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*The Little Cars in the Great Race* (2006)? It was released on DVD in 2006.

[image]

Comment: Does it have the scene described in the question with two cars driving slowly on a highway and talking about a race? If so, you should edit this answer to specify that.

Answer (score 5):

Might it be the 2015 Chinese film *[The Autobots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Autobots)*?

[image: Movie poster for The Autobots]

> *The Autobots* (simplified Chinese: 汽车人总动员; traditional Chinese: 汽車人總動員; pinyin: Qìchērén Zǒngdòngyuán) is a 2015 Chinese computer-animated motorsports comedy film directed by Zhuo Jianrong. It was released on July 4, 2015. The film received heavy criticism for its plot, animation quality, characters, and being a direct plagiarism and knockoff of Pixar’s *Cars 2*.

Here, the cars are explicitly regular cars with AI chips that make them sapient in a world that also has humans.

You can see some footage in a review by a guy viewing an online copy of the film that seems to have retained its native Cantonese dubbing, with Vietnamese dubbed over it.

Comment: Not that at all . Im from western europe, it was a ripoff but not that much.

Answer (score 5):

It's still later than the time period you state, but possibly the 2017 animated film by The Asylum, *[CarGo](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6680792/)*?

[image: Front cover of CarGo]

> A young car learns the importance of family when he embarks on a mission to rescue his father who's been sent to Clunker Island to be re-purposed as junk metal.

### Trailer

I found a copy online, and early on, there's a scene where Vin is talking to Danny (and later rapping) about how Danny isn't going to get anywhere going to school, and that he needs to do something cool like join a street race instead.